# Implication from an asymptotic equation.

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

Let $(z_n)$ be some zero sequence, $\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n=0$.

Assume the equation
$$
(n-1)\cdot z_n+O(n\cdot z_n^2)+\log(z_n)=0\text{ as }n\to\infty.
$$
holds.

> > Show that this implies $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot z_n^2=0$.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(n)=O(nz_n^2)$, that is $|f(n)|\le C|nz_n^2|$ for sufficiently large $n$.

Let $r_n = (n-1)z_n + f(n) + \log(z_n)$. Multiplying by $z_n$ and solving for $nz_n^2$ yields:

$$ n z_n^2 = r_nz_n + z_n^2 - z_n\log(z_n) - z_nf(n)   $$

Taking the absolute values and applying the triangle inequality then gives

$$|nz_n^2| \le |r_nz_n+z_n^2 - z_n\log(z_n)| + |z_n| \cdot C |nz_n^2|  $$

Hence

$$|nz_n^2| \le \underbrace{\frac{1}{1-|z_n|C}}_{\to 1}|\underbrace{r_nz_n}_{\to 0}+\underbrace{z_n^2}_{\to 0} - \underbrace{z_n\log(z_n)}_{\to 0}| \longrightarrow 0$$

Comment: I think multiplying by $z_n$ and solving for $nz_n^2$ gives $nz_n^2=r_nz_n+z_n^2-z_nf(n)-z_n\log(z_n)$. I am not sure whether this influences the rest of your proof.

Comment: @mathfemi Yes, my bad. But no it doesn't really affect the proof.

Comment: @mathfemi in asymptotics constants rarely matter ;-)

Comment: How do you get the last inequality from the one before? How do you know that, f.e..,$z_n\log(z_n)\to 0$?

Comment: @mathfemi subtract $|z_n|\cdot C \cdot |n z_n^2|$ and then divide by $1 -
 |z_n| C$. Make yourself clear why this doesn't potentially flip the $\le$ sign. $\lim_{x\to 0} x \log(x) = 0$ is fairly well know.

Comment: Ok, I See: $\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n\log(z_n)$ is the same here as $\lim_{x\to 0}x\log(x)$ which is 0 by L‘Hospital. But why $\lim_{n\to\infty}r_nz_n=0$ is not totally clear to me. Is this because $r_n=0$ as $n\to\infty$ by assumption?

Comment: @mathfemi Yes, by assumption both $z_n \to 0$ and $r_n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!